# handlebars each and using @key as parameter inside value of input field

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a problem trying to iterate through the array using each helper in handlebars.

here is my array

```
 let connectedAnalysis =[
       {
          id:req.body.connectedTo,
          name:req.body.connectedToName
        }
      ]
```

and with data it looks like

```
[
   {
    id: [ '5d36fbd59605220fa6e19feb', '5d40c10a178e7e26289a367c' ],
    name: [ 'analysis2', 'analysis2' ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to do this in order to get li tag with analysis name and hidden input with analysis id

```
    <ul class="list-inline my-3 connAnalysisUl">
     {{#each connectedAnalysis}
      {{#each name}}
       <li class="list-inline-item">{{this}}
       <small class="ml-1 float-right">x</small>
       <input type="hidden" name="connectedTo[]" value={{../this.id.[@key]}}>
       </li>
       {{/each}}
     {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

I'm trying to get id as a value in the input field and I'm trying to use @key but this is not working, how can I use index value as parameter inside my value tag? Or what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

this is resolved by creating a new array which is more appropriate to use in this situation

```
let connectedAnalysis = []
    for(i=0; i<req.body.connectedTo.length; i++) {
      connectedAnalysis.push({'id':req.body.connectedTo[i], 'name':req.body.connectedToName[i]})
    }
```

so I get something like

```
[
  { id: '5d36fbd59605220fa6e19feb', name: 'firstAnalysis' },
  { id: '5d46d2c9902f2d41ac4a6e22', name: 'secondAnalysis' }
]
```

but still, I would like to hear if it is possible to do it using array from the first example

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in [lookup helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) like this

```
<ul class="list-inline my-3 connAnalysisUl">
  {{#each connectedAnalysis}}
    {{#each name}}
      <li class="list-inline-item">{{this}}
       <small class="ml-1 float-right">x</small>
       <input type="hidden" name="connectedTo[]" value={{lookup ../id @key}}>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```